# Ubuntu 14.04 on ancient MacBook. Wireless issues

Tags: wireless, broadcom, macbook

So I decided to resurrect my old MacBook with the addition of ubuntu 14.04. The install went smoothly and I was happy to see that I had Wi-Fi drivers.

However I cannot surf nor even ping my router.  I'm getting an ipv4 address assigned and my router is able to see my connection to it but pinging by ip or name gets me "destination host unreachable"

Ping localhost works just fine so I assume the card is working.

I'm relatively new to Linux based troubleshooting, what more information can I provide to help?

EDIT: Wireless troubleshooting script results: http://pastebin.com/KrPp4dRu

Strange thing is that it started working last night and this morning.  I suspended the laptop this morning by closing the lid, when I woke it up this afternooon we're back to this.

Edit: lshw results show b43 drivers are being used as recommended for my PCI-ID

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: 00:1e:c2:b2:c1:5b
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=b43 driverversion=3.19.0-47-generic firmware=666.2 ip=192.168.0.199 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
```

ping results:

```
jon@macbook:~$ ping -W 0.5 -c 4 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.199 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.199 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.199 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.199 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3016ms
pipe 3

jon@macbook:~$ ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.199 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.199 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.199 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.199 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3015ms
pipe 2
```

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. You could also try going through [this recent answer by me](/a/727470/175814).

Comment: Updated. Still nothing. Weirdly if I connect via Ethernet I can ping out using "ping -I wlan0" which is supposed to use the wifi card.  If I remove or disable the ethernet I go back to being unable to ping out

Comment: Did you try the solutions to the [central question for BCM43xx chipsets](/q/55868/175814)?

Comment: Looking closer at the network diagnostics log, both of your network adapters seem to work fine with IP addresses and gateways retrieved through DHCP. This looks like a network configuration issue, not a device driver issue. Can you please post the output of steps 2 and 3 of [this answer](/a/727470/175814)?

Comment: added.  I can't really see how it's my gateway unless there's a specific setting in there that these drivers can't handle.  I have no problems with any of my other devices and given that the ethernet connection works fine I can only assume it's a wireless setting specifically.

**update** played with router settings.  Turned channel width from "Auto(20/40Mhz)" to "20Mhz".  Currently able to surf.  Will stress test for a while and report back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a wireless configuration issue.  Having installed the correct drivers using:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

I was still unable to get any data in or out via wifi.  I played around with my router settings and the one that worked was channel width.

By setting my channel width to 20Mhz from Auto(20/40Mhz) I was instantly able to ping and surf.

Hope this helps others in this situation.